# Is there a Pharmacology Textbook that Satisfies the Conditions listed in the Body of this Question?

Tags: pharmacology, book-recommendation

The conditions are:

- As extensive and explanatory as *Goodman and Gilman's The Pharmacological Basis of Therapeutics, Twelfth Edition*
- With additional extensive and thoroughly explanatory information on drugs (e.g. flupirtine, piracetam, nefopam, etc.) that are used elsewhere in the developed/semi-developed (like Russia or China) world (e.g. European countries) but not in the US.
- Additional information about the medically recognised (in some of the world at least) herbs *cannabis sativa* and *hypericum perforatum* (St. John's wort; recognised in Germany).

If there is no such book then the European (or a European, like for instance the British equivalent. So long as said equivalent comes in English) equivalent of Goodman and Gilman's will be accepted.

Comment: We're encouraged to use Rang & Dale's pharmacology but I don't know if it will go into enough detail for you.  You might also want to try and get your hands on a BNF for the clinical side of pharmacology if you're interested in UK practices.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: If you found the book you are searching for do tell us.

Comment: @RoryM : If you convert your comment into an answer this question may be saved from deletion.

Answer (score 0):

A title called *Essentials of Medical Pharmacology* fulfills these criteria and is quite popular in India.

Reference to the current edition:

Tripathi KD. Essentials of medical pharmacology. 8th ed. New Delhi: Jaypee. 2019; 1064 p.